# What is the minimum buffer size needed to initialize .ts (transport stream) file using FFMPEG

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, decode

I can play .ts files using FFMPEG by passing full file. Now I have to play .ts as a buffer. Now I'm reading a ts file say 188*200 means 200 packets. Can anybody tell me what is minimum buffer size or minimum number packets needed to initialize ts playback.